# Combining 2 similar lua scripts logitech

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

First code

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock")  then
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(-2, 0)
                Sleep(10)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
            end

        end
end
```

Second code

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    OutputLogMessage("Event: "..event.." Arg: "..arg.."\n")
    if IsKeyLockOn("numlock")  then
            if IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
            repeat
                MoveMouseRelative(2, 0)
                Sleep(10)
                until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
            end

        end
end
```

The 1st one moves my mouse to the left, while the 2nd one moves it to the right

Comment: Create a third function `moveMouseRelative` which accepts the relative position, call this function in both event callbacks.

Comment: @TheRealestOne - How would script determine where it should move the mouse: to the left or to the right?